# How can I download?

Tags: live-installation

I see no way to download an elementary OS trial. I'm not opposed to buying an OS, but I must experience it first.

I'm running Mint with the Cinnamon DM now, and the GTK3 system dialogs are so awful, they make using Mint Cinnamon like wading through molasses.

Answer (score 2):

On the download page, click on the custom button and set it to 0. After that you will see that the purchase button now says **Download**.

[image]